# jQuery to execute PHP MySQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here's what I've got. I'm trying to have jquery run a mysql query.

This is my PHP:

```
<select name="kingdom" id="kingdom" >
    <option value="standard">-- Kingdom --</option>
        <?php
            $the_d = $_POST['d'];
            $filter = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT sci_kingdom FROM tbl_lifedata WHERE sci_domain = '$the_d'");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter, MYSQL_NUM))
                    {
                        $row['name'];
                        //echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
                    }
        ?>
</select>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('#domain').change(function () {

    var selectval = $('#domain').val();

    $.post("search.php", {
        d: selectval
    }, function (data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
});
```

Right now I would just like to have jQuery spit out the values of the mysql result. When I have that working, I can have them populate a select box. What I get now is the html of search.php but nothing to do with the mysql query.

Comment: Note that your code has a SQL injection vulnerability on line 5.

Comment: You are not outputting the values from the query. You merely have `$row['name']` in the fetch loop. You're using numeric keys in the fetch, so `$row['name']` wouldn't be set anyway.

Comment: Were you able to print $_POST['d'] ??

Answer (score 2):

You should actually print what you are retrieving from the DB.

```
<select name="kingdom" id="kingdom" >
                <option value="standard">-- Kingdom --</option>
                <?php 
                $the_d = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['d']);//thanks to @Mansfield
                $filter = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT sci_kingdom FROM tbl_lifedata WHERE sci_domain = '".$the_d."'");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter, MYSQL_NUM))
                {
                    echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";

                }

                ?>
            </select>


 //or you can also use mysql_fetch_array($filter, MYSQL_ASSOC) if you want to print $row['name']
```

Updated answer:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="domain" id="domain"/>
<div class="result" id="result"></div>
<script>
$('#domain').change(function() {

            var selectval = $('#domain').val();

            $.post(
                "test.php", 
                { d : selectval },
                function(data) {
                    $('.result').html(data);//my bad should be displaying data retrenched
                }
                );
});
</script>

///test.php contents:

<?php
print $the_d = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['d']);// see if the scripts are working fine until here, if so, then see below.
//test your mysql result by doing a print_r($row.)    
?>
```

**post the result of print_r($row);**

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the real escape string! What do I need to do to my jQuery to get it to populate? Right now, after these changes, it still isn't working.

Comment: Yes! It comes up with the value of the select onchange. What can I do from here??

Comment: How would I do that? How can I get the results from the query and use them to populate the select box?

Comment: Hmm..the only thing that is happening is the $('.result').html(selectval) is appearing, nothing from the mysql query appears

Comment: My bad, I was testing this and I left the selectval like that, it should update the result div with data but not selectval

Comment: No worries, but it the query is still not working/producing results. I really do appreciate your help on this. I just cannot figure out why it won't run the query, Ive looked at every google search and this is how is says to do it

Comment: Ok , can you print the $row contents here? I will try and check what's wrong. 
Just make the PHP script to print out the $row, its ok it the result div gets updated with the $row. Jus do a print_r($row);